# Elastic Search Post API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to write java api from which I can post in to elastic search index. I have already written for GET.  I could not find any documentation for post.
Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is already a java client :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_maven_repository.html